# como saber cuantos registro devuelve una consulta sql server 2012 con php

Tags: sql, servidor

tengo la siguiente consulta  `SELECT * FROM REPORTE` y quiero saber cómo hago para que cuente cuántos registros hay en la tabla, en SQL Server 2012. Con php no encuentro como hacer para realizar ciertas funciones en base a la cantidad de registros.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REPORTE` Así puedes obtener el total de registros en tu tabla.

Comment: ya intento con SELECT COUNT(campo) FROM REPORTE??

Answer (score 2):

No depende de PHP lo que quieres realizar, es una operación en lenguaje SQL que debes ejecutar.

La forma es usando una función de agregación, que en este caso es `COUNT()` la cual puede indicarse de estos modos

1. `COUNT(*)` Contará todos los registros de la tabla, considera que el uso del comodín * contará incluso aquellos valores `NULL` o `duplicados`
2. `COUNT(id)` Usando para contar los registros de la tabla, apoyandose de la columna id

TU SQL DEBERÍA VERSE ASÍ

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TablaName;
```

Para por ejemplo indicarte como resultado

```
//20 si es que tuvieras 20 registros hechos
```

**Te pongo el siguiente ejemplo**

Tenemos la siguiente tabla con registros de usuarios, algunos de ellos repetidos

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
   name VARCHAR(100),
   email VARCHAR(100)
);
```

Estos son los registros de las tablas

```
INSERT INTO usuarios
VALUES
('alfred', 'mail@example.com'),
('beto', 'mail@example.com'),
('daniel', 'mail@example.com'),
('pedro', 'mail@example.com'),
('beto', 'mail@example.com'),
('daniela', 'mail@example.com');
```

Si hago un `COUNT(*)` obtengo lo siguiente

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuarios;
//retorna 6
```

Si por el contrario ahora quiero el conteo pero solo de los valores únicos, debo indicar en lugar del operador de comodín `*`, el nombre de la columna y la palabra reservada `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) FROM usuarios;
//retorna 5
```